# How to integrate WebStorm with SVN 1.8 on OS X (without Xcode)

Tags: macos, svn, webstorm

How can I integrate WebStorm (version 10) with SVN 1.8 with no Xcode required?

Answer (score 4):

Brief: you have to install the version 1.8 command line of SVN and set on Version Control > Subversion commando line client path.

Personally I prefer to use brew. Just run `brew install svn` and after that list the location with `brew list svn`.
At this point you'll have the path, like that '/usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.8.13/bin/svn'.

You have to config in WebStorm preferences, put this path in 'command line client'. [image: webstorm config]
That's it, now your WebStorm will have the 1.8 checkout option enabled!

[image: tadaaa]